# iOS 7 ScrollView Not Scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm having a problem that I've seen a fair few comments/answers to - I've tried these but am still having no luck.

I'm using iOS 7 and have a view on which I have a `UIScrollView`.

I've connected the `UIScrollView` up using an `IBOutlet`, then set the contentSize in `viewDidLoad`.

However it doesn't seem to scroll. I have AutoLayout switched on and don't want it off (I've seem some answers work if I switch off but I don't feel thats the right solution in my case).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the content size in viewdidlayoutsubviews instead.

Comment: Please post your relevant code, layout constraints, etc. There is no silver bullet for getting scroll views to work with auto layout - we need to see what you're doing so far.

Comment: Awesome setting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews worked! I'll need to read up to understand why it worked there though! Thank yous

Comment: No problem :) Maybe I should write that out as a proper answer along w an explanation to make for easier viewing for answer seekers...

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, try setting the content size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of in `viewDidLoad` -- that way the scrollview content size you set is no longer affected by auto layout since auto layout already "did layout [the] subviews."

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting `Leading space`, `Trailing space`, and `Top space` `Layout constraints` of the subview in the `UIScrollView` to the `UIScrollView` (`Container`) itself.